# Anyone found a Fix for bootstrap 3.0 modal move the NAV

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, nav

I download like many the new Bootstrap 3.0
Awesome new release.
I encounter a problem with the Modal that was not there in the RC2.

When you trigger a modal the NAV move left 20px or so.
When it close everything go back.

Any clue of the problem or a fix.

[Bootstrap Javascript section Try the modal.](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/)

Comment: I finally found the FIX in bootstrap.css at line 5599 put 0 instead of 15px. DONE

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54809867/11096631) using bootstrap v3.3.7 might help you.

Answer (score 1):

I think better remove this all for solving this problem and for didn't create any new.

```
body.modal-open,
.modal-open .navbar-fixed-top,
.modal-open .navbar-fixed-bottom {
 margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work for me, now my entire page margin-rights on modal click, but your code is applying to entire body so maybe that's it.

Comment: This worked for me remove body class and use padding-right instead.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap 3.0? There is no such problem in new versions.

Comment: im using 3.3.2 pulled from the cdn https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css and https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 0):

```
    .modal-open .navbar-fixed-top{
      padding-right: 12px;
    }
```

This did the trick for me. Change '-top' to '-bottom' depending on your nav bar.