# Twitter Bootstrap modal opening/closing causes fixed header to jump

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, dialog, modal-dialog, scrollbar

I am almost done with a simple 2-page website for my registered domain names.
Unfortunately I have one small issue I can't seem to fix: a jumpy header when a Twitter Bootstrap modal opens and closes.
On mobile devices there's no problem. The problem only occurs in larger viewports like desktops and laptops.

## How to recreate

1. Open http://www.domains.cloudlabz.nl/domains in a webbrowser and **make sure you get a vertical scrollbar** by lowering the viewport height.
2. Click on one of the blue 'more info' buttons.
3. Notice the jumping header and disappearing scrollbar once the modal opens.
4. Close the modal and notice the header jumping back and the scrollbar reappearing.

Check the following image (same result in Opera, Safari, Firefox and Chrome):

[image: Jumping header issue]

## What I'd like

I'd like the header to stop jumping when opening/closing a modal. The fact the scrollbar disappears is not an issue. Actually, I would like it to stay like that.

## Update

I noticed the jumping header only occurs with fixed position elements such as my header (added Bootstrap class navbar-fixed-top). It even occurs on the Bootstrap website itself: http://getbootstrap.com/javascripts. Go to the 'Modals > Optional Sizes' area on a desktop and click one of the buttons. You'll see the right side menu jumping back and forth.

When the modal opens, the class .modal-open is added to the body element (thanks for pointing that out @Pred). It adds a padding of 15px to the right, which is the same width as the scrollbar gutter. This prevents the body from jumping back and forth.

Unfortunately this padding apparently does not apply to fixed elements.

Comment: Please add the relavant code to your question, or at least set up a fiddle to reproduce the issue. This way your questions remains relevant to others after you fixed it.

Comment: I don't see any problem in Safari or Chrome.

Comment: @PeterVR The problem is I don't know which piece of code triggers the issue.

Comment: @JoseMagana Have you tried it on a Mac machine? I haven't checked it on Windows/Linux machines yet. I'll edit the original post a bit.

Comment: @PeterdeLeeuw I'm using a Macbook Pro retina 13"

Comment: @JoseMagana I added a picture to the original post. You don't see something like this happening when you 'create' a vertical scrollbar by reducing the height of your browser window?

Comment: @PeterdeLeeuw Oh I see. This is based on your system preferences for your scrollbar. What Safari is doing is pushing/squeezing content so the scrollbar doesn't go over anything the viewer might want to see. I doubt you can do anything to deal with this, because it depends on the browser and settings for each individual viewer. The reason it's moving when you open and close the modal is because the scrollbar disappears with an open modal, and reappears when scrolling is actually an option. If you must, you can change your general settings to "Show scrollbars: when scrolling".

Comment: Can't reproduce this, domains are not found and bootstrap link is not working

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I seemed to have found a quick fix for my issue. It uses a piece of javascript to add extra style to the header (15px padding-right) to prevent it from jumping.
This might not be the best solution but for now it works just fine.

Since there were no issues on viewports smaller than 768px (mobile) this piece of code only adds the extra 15px to larger viewports such as desktops and laptops

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        // Dirty fix for jumping scrollbar when modal opens

        $('#requestModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
            if ($(window).width() > 768) {
                $(".navbar-default").css("padding-right","15px");
            }
        });

        $('#requestModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
            if ($(window).width() > 768) {
                $(".navbar-default").css("padding-right","0px");
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

If you know a better solution (preferably CSS3 only), please let me know.
Thanks for all the help!

Comment: The scrollbar has a different widths on various browsers, so while this might work with the browser and OS you are using giving a set padding to your site will surly break it for users on other systems and browsers. Have a look here for a possible js solution taking into account the varying scrollbar widths. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14040#issuecomment-52120453

Answer (score 31):

Bootstrap adds `class="modal-open"` and `padding-right: 15px;` to `body` when the modal is shown. To remove the right shift and keep the scroll bar add this to your css:

```
body.modal-open {
  overflow: inherit;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Tried in bootstrap 3.3.4

Comment: Nice, but only if you know your modal won't need a scrollbar. Otherwise you might get a double scrollbar. And what's more, body will be scrollable with open modal.

Comment: @mizurnix I guess you can get the scroll-bar width with some JS and then adjusting the padding dynamically. In my case, I just wanted the most minimal solution and the double scroll-bar was not an issue.

Comment: Worked for `bootstrap 5.1` as well.

Answer (score 5):

As you usually put Bootstrap `navbar` as a direct child of the `body` container:

```
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">...</nav>
</body>
```

You can use the `body` `padding-right` value, calculated in the Bootstrap core code to prevent it from "jumping" when opening a modal window, to fix the `navbar` issue as well . A pure CSS solution is below:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
  padding-right: inherit;
}
```

Easy as that.

Comment: This is a solution that fits the cause of the behaviour the best.

When modal is opened, `.modal-open` class is added to the `body` which sets `overflow: hidden`. To remedy that, bootstrap js also adds a padding to the body - but that padding is **not a constant** 15px, but rather a calculated value, depending on browser rendering (since the overflow bar can have different widths.

`padding-right: inherit` solution works perfectly because the navbar padding will now always fit the dynamically added body padding.

Comment: @Olia.Bn, if your navbar is not a direct child of the body container (as it was in my case), you may want to try another approach I've described in my 2nd answer to this question. It adds `overflow-y: scroll;` to a navbar  container when the modal window is open, thus pushing its content by the same value as the body padding.

Answer (score 4):

When the modal opens, the "modal-open" class is added to the HTML `<body>` element which hides overflow.  You can change this by over-writing the "modal-open" class with `overflow: inherit`.  This will keep the scrollbar in view, just as it is when the modal is closed.  Keep in mind that this will change the overflow option whenever any modal is opened on the page.  Hope this helps.  Good luck!

Comment: This prevents the header menu from jumping but unfortunately also keeps the scrollbar in sight. It causes weird behavior on small height desktop screens such as scrolling the content behind the modal instead of the modal itself.

Comment: That's my bad; I thought that you wanted the scrollbar to stay. In reference to a css solution to your answer, try something like: 
@media (min-width: 768px) {
 .modal-open #requestModal .navbar-default {
  padding-right: 15px;
 }
}

Answer (score 4):

All this happens because of this part of code in bootstrap.js:

```
Modal.prototype.setScrollbar = function () {
    var bodyPad = parseInt((this.$body.css('padding-right') || 0), 10)
    if (this.scrollbarWidth) this.$body.css('padding-right', bodyPad + this.scrollbarWidth)
}
```

That annoying problem happens in Firefox 32.0 (Gecko/20100101) and Chromium Version 37.0.2062.94 (Webkit 537.36) (Ubuntu 14.04). Not happens in QupZilla Version 1.6.6 (WebKit 537.21).

For me, the dirty fix is to comment the conditional line, after that it works in all browsers I tested (including some android's browsers).

NOTE: if you comment that line, you should be careful with the size of your modals since bootstrap will not create enough space for the new scrollbar.

Regards.

Comment: emphasis on **dirty**

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to add:

```
.modal-open .navbar-fixed-top {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

to prevent its content from jumping. Again, easy as that.

Answer (score 3):

This one only works if you know your page content is longer than the viewport (so any long scrolling page). You can just add the following to your CSS -

```
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.modal-open {
  padding-right: 0!important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I came around same issue and I solved it as follows

just add

```
body.modal-open {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 0!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I manually change bootstap.js:

before change

```
Modal.prototype.setScrollbar = function () {
    var bodyPad = parseInt((this.$body.css('padding-right') || 0), 10)
    if (this.bodyIsOverflowing) this.$body.css('padding-right', bodyPad + this.scrollbarWidth)
  }

  Modal.prototype.resetScrollbar = function () {
    this.$body.css('padding-right', '')
  }
```

after change:

```
  Modal.prototype.setScrollbar = function () {
    var bodyPad = parseInt((this.$body.css('padding-right') || 0), 10)
    var headerPad = parseInt(($('.navbar-fixed-top').css('padding-right') || 0), 10)
    if (this.bodyIsOverflowing) this.$body.css('padding-right', bodyPad + this.scrollbarWidth)
    if (this.bodyIsOverflowing) $('.navbar-fixed-top').css('padding-right', headerPad + this.scrollbarWidth)
  }

  Modal.prototype.resetScrollbar = function () {
    this.$body.css('padding-right', '')
    $('.navbar-fixed-top').css('padding-right', '')
  }
```

Comment: Please, add some explanation to your changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have a structure:

```
<html>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">...</nav>
  <section>
    <div class="container">...</div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="container">...</div>
  </section>
  <footer>...</foter>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using this CSS:

```
body.modal-open {padding-right: 0 !important}
body.modal-open nav,
body.modal-open section,
body.modal-open footer {padding-right: 17px !important}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your CSS:

```
body {
  overflow: inherit;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 4 `sticky-top`, use the following snippet. Tested all the CSS solutions on this page but none worked for Bootstrap 4.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('body').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
        $('.sticky-top').css('margin-left', '-=0px');
    });

    $('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('.sticky-top').css('margin-left', 'auto');
    });

</script>
```

My page design was as follows

```
<header class="container">
    <div class="row">

    </div>
</header>

<div class="container sticky-top">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        This div jumped/shifted 17px to the right when opening a modal
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it can be solved by adding comments or remove these two lines `right: 0;` and `left: 0;` in bootstrap.css file:

```
.navbar-fixed-top,
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  /* right: 0;
  left: 0; */
  z-index: 1030;
}
```

Note: I use bootstrap v3.3.7

Answer (score 0):

In 4.5, the following code solved my issue of the fixed header sliding left.

```
body.modal-open {
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 0!important;
  }
  .modal-open .fixed-top {
    padding-right: inherit!important;
  }
```