# Bootstrap modal-open causing body to have style="padding-right: 15px;"

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On my `bootstrap 3.3.7` website, the entire body gets a `'style="15px"'` when the modal is opened. This is moving my top navigation (fixed nav) `15px` right when I open my modal. I cannot use `CSS` to remove the padding since it is an element.

I have tried to use `'left: 15px'` on the body for `modal-open` class (and various other `CSS` options) to no avail. I did not add this to my `HTML` so it's a bootstrap thing. The link to the modal is within the top navigation, but when the link is clicked the modal popup `HTML` shows up below the nav div when I inspect element.

Here's the [page](https://iigkid.github.io/jekyll-mexpro/), click on 'Log In' button in top right.I expect the navigation to stay put when I click the modal. I don't want it to move. Please help

Comment: can u create jsfiddle or paste ur code here

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/04dseckz/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap modal opening/closing causes fixed header to jump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274244/twitter-bootstrap-modal-opening-closing-causes-fixed-header-to-jump)

Comment: Working for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65027287/7186739

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap also add class on body `.modal-open` u can play with this class

```
   .modal-open .navbar-fixed-top {
        right: 15px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change css style didn't worked for me for this padding-right addition but remove `this._disableOverFlow()` 
in bootstrap.min.js from

```js
this._disableOverFlow(), 
this._setElementAttributes(this._element, Ie, e => e + t), 
this._setElementAttributes(Le, Ie, e => e + t), 
this._setElementAttributes(Oe, De, e => e - t);
```

worked for me

bootstrap v5.3.2